# ACL without server side logic

Tags: mongodb, acl

Would this be possible to have ACL for REST API implemented inside stored procedures in Mongo?
Is this a good idea?
Doing this way I could completely omit the need for application server - the ACL logic would be handled by Mongo and the app logic would reside on client side.

Comment: MongoDB does not possess stored procedures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **no**

MongoDB can run [javascript functions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/#running-js-scripts-in-mongo-on-mongod-host) on the server in a few contexts, but they are never stored in the database. So you would **have** to send the javascript code to the server, because there are no "stored procedures" in MongoDB. So implementing an ACL in your case would mean sending this "ACL implementation" code from the client, which is not secure enough. There must be a server between the client and your  Mongo database.

Comment: You can get stored javascript and eval the stored javascript function but due to how javascript is run and interpreted within MongoDB it is not stored procedures and should not be considered as such.

Comment: I thought those functions are stored. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Found a solution!**

Being extremely lazy person I found out that [Deployd](http://deployd.com/) does exactly what I want (provide a backend without writing much code). The ACLs are easily configured and the setup is very easy.